# Mapping sets of points with affine transformation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-image, affinetransform

There are 2 sets of points:

[image]

The points are in separate pandas dataframes (python 3), stored as the points in rows and the values of the x and y positions in columns:

```
Centroid X µm   Centroid Y µm
```

0   1243.4,          662.69

1   1254.5,          666.70

I have matched the points in a different program that gives me the affine transformation matrix that will overlay the two graphs:

-0.002,      -1.000,           19629.301,

1.000,       -0.002,           3414.193

However, the other program does not let me save the transformed image, which is why I have extracted the points here. So I would like to apply this affine transformation matrix to these two columns of one of the dataframes so the points overlap.

Comment: When you say that they have to be normalized, rotated, and flipped, does that mean that you already have a particular transformation in mind, or should it be a parameter in the optimization? (The latter is drastically more complicated.)

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, I have updated the problem. The transformation I have in mind is listed as the transformation matrix. I have visually optimized the transformation in the program that gave me the transformation matrix, so no further optimization parameter is needed.

Answer (score 1):

We can convert the `pandas` dataframes to `numpy` arrays, estimate the affine transform and apply the estimated transform as follows:

```
# randomly-generated sample datapoints
data1 =  np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=np.zeros(2), cov=[[10,0],[0,1]], size=1000)
data2 = np.zeros_like(data1)
# apply an affine transform, 
# e.g., apply rotation + translation
# to transform data1 into data2 
# (could apply shear / scaling here too)
tx, ty, theta = 2, -2, np.pi/6
print(tx, ty, theta)
# 2 -2 0.5235987755982988
data2[:,0] = data1[:,0]*np.cos(theta)-data1[:,1]*np.sin(theta) + tx
data2[:,1] = data1[:,0]*np.sin(theta)+data1[:,1]*np.cos(theta) + ty
# visualize the datasets
```

[image]

Now use `estimate_transform()` from `skimage.tramsform` to estimate the affine transformation using least-squares:

```
from skimage.transform import estimate_transform
tform = estimate_transform('affine', data1, data2)
par = tform.params
print(par) # the estimated affine transformation matrix (in homogeneous coordinates)
# [[ 0.8660254 -0.5        2.       ]
# [ 0.5        0.8660254 -2.       ]
# [ 0.         0.         1.       ]]
tx_, ty_ = par[0,-1], par[1,-1]
theta_ = np.arccos(par[0,0])
print(tx_, ty_, theta_)
# 1.9999999999999996 -1.9999999999999993 0.5235987755982978
```

Notice from above that the estimated parameters are very close to the original affine transformation parameters.

Now use the parameters estimated to transform `data1` to `data2_` and visualize.

```
data2_ = np.zeros_like(data1)
data2_[:,0] = data1[:,0]*np.cos(theta_)-data1[:,1]*np.sin(theta_) + tx_
data2_[:,1] = data1[:,0]*np.sin(theta_)+data1[:,1]*np.cos(theta_) + ty_
plt.scatter(data1[:,0], data1[:,1], alpha=0.2, label='data1')
plt.scatter(data2_[:,0], data2_[:,1], alpha=0.2, label='data2 estimated')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

```
np.allclose(data2, data2_)
# True
```

The original `data2` and the `data2_` obtained by applying the affine transformation with estimated parameters are almost identical, as we can see from above.